# Kaggle Titanic with tflearn neural network

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning, kaggle

I have solved the Titanic problem with logistic regression, now I want solve the problem with neural network. But my model always return **1**, that means **survived**. for every test input. Maybe there is a problem in my model. How could I solve this?

```
train_data = pd.read_csv('data/train.csv')
test_data = pd.read_csv('data/test.csv')

#Some data cleaning process
#......


X_train = train_data.drop("Survived",axis=1).as_matrix()
Y_train = train_data["Survived"].as_matrix().reshape((891,1))
X_test  = test_data.drop("PassengerId",axis=1).as_matrix()


net = tflearn.input_data(shape=[None, 6])
net = tflearn.fully_connected(net, 32)
net = tflearn.fully_connected(net, 32)
net = tflearn.fully_connected(net, 1, activation='softmax')
net = tflearn.regression(net)
model = tflearn.DNN(net)
model.fit(X_train, Y_train, n_epoch=10, batch_size=16, show_metric=True)

pred = model.predict(X_test)
print pred
```

Comment: Do you achieve the 80% or higher accuracy? My best neural network can do only 70% with `Sina` features

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using [softmax](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Softmax_function) as an activation layer in the output ensures that the sum of the outputs across all nodes in that layer is `1`. Since you only have a single node, and the output has to sum to `1`, it will always output `1` by definition.

You should never use softmax as your activation for a binary classification task. A better option is the [logistic function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_function), which I think tensorflow calls [sigmoid](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/sigmoid).

So instead of

```
net = tflearn.fully_connected(net, 1, activation='softmax')
```

try

```
net = tflearn.fully_connected(net, 1, activation='sigmoid')
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is a binary classification problem ie there are 2 possible outcomes. `0 or 1` . In the context of Titanic Problem `Not Survived or Survived`.

The output layer of the neural net should produce an output less than or equal to 1 or greater than or equal to 0. No other values will make sense in the context of binary classification.

Normally a cutoff is placed like `0.50`. If the predicted output of the net is greater than that cutoff, it is regarded as 1 else 0.

In order for things to work like this as said before the net should produce an output in the range [0, 1]. For this the activation function of the layer ie output layer must be `sigmoid`. It produces output in the range [0, 1]. To know more about sigmoid and other activation functions I recommend you to follow this [link](https://towardsdatascience.com/activation-functions-neural-networks-1cbd9f8d91d6).

In your code you can do it like this.

```
net = tflearn.fully_connected(net, 1, activation='sigmoid')
```